# Obtener los productos relacionados a sus categorías

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo dos tablas una de productos y otra de categorías, y quiero obtener las categorías y los productos que pertenecen a dicha categoría desde el controlador pero no obtengo el resultado esperado. De antemano gracias por su ayuda...

```
$categorias = DB::table('categorias')
                ->select('idcategoria', 'nombre')
                ->get();

    $productosxcat = [];            
    foreach ($categorias as $cat) {
        $productos = DB::table('producto')
            ->where('producto.id_categoria', '=', $cat->idcategoria)
            ->get();
        $productosxcat = $productos;
    }

    return [
        'categorias' => [$categorias, $productosxcat],
    ];
```

Comment: Si tengo los modelos correspondientes a cada tabla...

Comment: Si una categoría tiene muchos productos...

Comment: producto.id_categoria y categoria.idcategoria

Comment: producto->idproducto, categorias->idcategoria

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo los siguientes 2 modelos:

- Categoria
- Producto

Modelo Categoria

- Declaramos una propiedad protegida para el nombre de la tabla, si es que esta en su nombre no sigue las convenciones de Eloquent
- Declaramos la relación `hasMany()` para relacionar que una Categoría *tiene muchos productos*

---

```
class Categoria extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "categorias"; //nombre de la tabla
    protected $primaryKey = "idCategoria"; //llave primaria de la tabla categorías

    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Producto::class, "id_categoria", "idCategoria");
    }
}
```

Modelo Producto

- Declaramos una propiedad protegida para el nombre de la tabla, si es que esta en su nombre no sigue las convenciones de Eloquent
- Declaramos la relación `belongsTo()` para relacionar que un Producto *pertenece a una categoría*
- El segundo parámetro es la llave foránea en la tabla productos y la debemos declarar por que tampoco sigue la convención de nombre de laravel
- El tercer parámetro es la llave primaria del modelo actual que es `Categoria` y que al no seguir tampoco la convención de nombres pues debemos declararla

---

```
class Producto extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "productos";
    protected $primaryKey = "idProducto";

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class);
    }
}
```

La consulta:

```
$consulta = Categoria::with('productos')->get();
```

Lo que hacemos en esta consulta:

Obtenemos al modelo Categoria con sus productos relacionados por medio de la relación declarada

Comment: muchas gracias por la informacion ya lo implemente pero ahora solo me trae los productos de la ultima categoria registrada y no de todas: $categorias = DB::table('categorias')
                    ->select('idcategoria', 'nombre')
                    ->get();
                  
        foreach ($categorias as $cat) {
            $idcategoria = $cat->idcategoria;
            $consulta = Categoria::with('productos')->findOrFail($idcategoria);
        }

Comment: Si todos los productos de todas las categorias... Que pena creo que no formule bien la pregunta...

Comment: Listo ya me funciono muchas gracias por tu ayuda, esta implementando el Query Builder de laravel pero es como mas complicado hacerlo con el query builder, de nuevo muchas gracias...